# Smartcard verify pin apdu command problem in android

Tags: java, android, smartcard, apdu

I'm working on an android pos device. when I inserted the smart card and run the following command it gives me **9000** response and works fine :

**00 A4 00 00 08 610433BE00010001**

*CLA/INS/P1/P2/Lc/DATA*

but when I want to send pin verification command :

**00 20 00 00 02 80 12**
(the pin is 8012 for example)

It give me **6D00** error, which means the command not supported.

what's wrong with this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
every apdu command needs to transmit step by step, for example:

**select applet > check pin verify > get card registration info**

"before run any command on smartcard, i need to run select applet first!"

Answer (score 0):

You should send this APDU command to verify your pin:

```
00 20 00 00 04 38 30 31 32 instead of 00 20 00 00 02 80 12

04 => 4 bytes

38 => Hex of integer value of 8
30 => Hex of integer value of 0
31 => Hex of integer value of 1
32 => Hex of integer value of 2

and of course result should be 9000
```